# Loop does not work with react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop

My loop repetition does not work, I'm using React to render on the screen, but only one element appears and my array has 12 elements. Can someone tell me why?

```js
import React from 'react'
import '../custom/style.css'

export default props =>{

    const renderRows = () =>{
    const list = props.list || []
     for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var obj = list[i];
        return (
        <div key={obj.id}>
            <p>{obj.title}</p>
            <img src={obj.images.normal} />
            </div>
        )
    } 
    
}


    return(
        <div id="demo">
        {renderRows()}
        </div>
            
    )

}
```

Comment: You have a return statement inside your for loop. The function stops running at that point, and so only returns one element. Did you mean to do `list.map` instead of a for loop?

Comment: The map works to some extent, but it is an array of objects. And in the case of the image it is an object with three properties. How would I do to read? Example: "images": { "url" : "path", "url2": "path2"
  
}

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a `<div>` on the first loop iteration. You'll want to create an array and push all your elements there instead. I'd recommend using the `map` function i.e.

```
const renderRows = () => {
  const list = props.list || [];
  return list.map(obj => (
    <div key={obj.id}>
      <p>{obj.title}</p>
      <img src={obj.images.normal} />
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Comment: The map works to some extent, but it is an array of objects. And in the case of the image it is an object with three properties. How would I do to read?<br/> Example: "images": { "url" : "path", "url2": "path2"
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Mapping over the `div`s is easier. The loop `return`s after the first iteration, thus only one `<div>`.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../custom/style.css'

export default rows = () => {
  return (
    props.list && props.list.map(obj => {
      <div key={obj.id}>
        <p>{obj.title}</p> 
        <img src={obj.images.normal}/> 
      </div>
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: The map works to some extent, but it is an array of objects. And in the case of the image it is an object with three properties. How would I do to read? Example: "images": { "url" : "path", "url2": "path2"
  
}

Comment: I got it using JSON.stringiify